# How can I add the compilation date to java project automatically

Tags: java, date, compilation

Is there a way in Java to have a string contain the date the program was compiled? When I start my program, I want the date it was last updated to appear without having to manually update it before I compile every time. Is there possibly a setting in eclipse I can use to insert the date in the code every time I compile it?

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String date = "2014-12-29"; //The string I want to automatically update.

        System.out.println("Last updated: "+date);

    }
}
```

Comment: One of your problems is going to be that "the program" has more than one compilation date.  Do you want the date the main class was compiled?  The most recent date that any class was compiled?  How about a date that resources were updated?  You might consider setting up a build process which updates a resource that contains the date the build was done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a file to your project which contains the date. Read it from the file when you start. Use a tool like Gradle, Maven or Ant to build your project. All of them have one way or the other to update the file with the date.